# Инициализация массива-члена класса в конструкторе

Tags: visual-c++, c++

Хочу инициализировать Массив х в конструкторе класса А.
Хочу это сделать не явным образом-присваивая поэлементно, после объявления. Хочу сделать непосредственно при объявлении. Для этого описываю конструктор следующим образом:

```
class A 
{
    public:
    A();
    int x[10];
};
//...// 
A::A():x({4,3,3,5,6,3,3,3,3,4})
{ }
```

Но компилятор сильно (несколько раз) ругает на такой синтаксис.

p.s. да, можно было бы забить на это, но хочу разобраться-как это работает.

Comment: `Visual studio` пока еще не поддерживает списки инициализации `C++11`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Компилятор явно подсказывает - удалите круглые скобки (*warning: list-initializer for non-class type must not be parenthesized [enabled by default]*). После этого компилируется без предупреждений и работает.

```
A::A():x{4,3,3,5,6,3,3,3,3,4} {
}
```

Comment: Вы были на минуту раньше :)

Comment: более того, мой ответ точнее:)

Comment: KoVadim@, ругается!
может у меня просто старый компилятор-2002 года, и в нем был другой синтаксис..

Comment: не нравится ему эта фигурная скобка

Comment: не пользуйтесь древними компиляторами. У них не другой синтаксис - у них другой стандарт, тем более у компиляторов от MS. (сейчас ситуация немножко лучше, но не настолько).

Comment: @KoVadim, я бы с радостью. Но проект не переносится на новую версию. Все по синтаксису исправил, он с компилировался, но потом написал, что на данном компьютере работать не будет(не помню точной ошибки). короче переноситься отказался

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте [так](http://ideone.com/H7M3qq):

```
class A
{
public:
    A() : x{1, 2, 3, 4}
    {
    }
    int x[10];
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```